# problem nestjs - Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthenticationService (?)

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

The application stops immediately at startup, other modules have not been checked yet, so the error is unlikely in them.

**authentication.service.ts**

```
import { HttpException, HttpStatus, Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateUserDto } from 'src/users/dto/createUser.dto';
import { UserService } from 'src/users/user/user.service';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    constructor(@Inject() private readonly userService: UserService){}
    public async regiser(registartionData:CreateUserDto){
    const hashingPassword = await bcrypt.hash(registartionData.passwordHash, 10);
    try{
        const createUser = await this.userService.create({
            ...registartionData,
            passwordHash: hashingPassword
        })
        createUser.passwordHash = undefined;
        return createUser;
    }
    catch(err){
        throw new HttpException('Something went wrong', HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
public async getAuthenticationUser(email:string, textPassword:string){
    try{
        const user = await this.userService.findByEmail(email);
        await this.verifyPassword(textPassword,user.passwordHash);
        user.passwordHash = undefined;
        return user;
    }
    catch(err){
        throw new HttpException('Wrong credentials provided', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
private async verifyPassword(password:string, hashingPassword:string){
    const isMatching = await bcrypt.compare(password, hashingPassword);
    if(!isMatching) throw new HttpException('Wrong credentials provided', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
}
```

**auth.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { UsersModule } from 'src/users/users.module';
import { AuthController } from '../controllers/auth/auth.controller';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication/authentication.service';
import { LocalStrategy } from './authentication/local.strategy';

@Module({
  imports:[UsersModule, PassportModule, ],
  providers: [AuthenticationService, LocalStrategy],
  controllers:[AuthController],
  exports: [AuthenticationService]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**this error**

```
 Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthenticationService (?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If dependency is a provider, is it part of the current AuthModule?
- If dependency is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AuthModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing dependency */ ]
  })
```

I don't understand error, export and provide auth service. I don't use auth service in other modules.

Comment: in AuthenticationService  you have:   constructor(@Inject() private readonly userService: UserService){},  But in AuthModule there is non.  Are you sure UsersModule exports UserService?

Comment: **user.module.ts**                                                                                                                                         ```import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './user/user.service';

@Module({
  providers: [UserService],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UsersModule {}```

Comment: Why are you using `@Inject()` without a dependency token?

Comment: @Inject() is not needed, I removed it, but **new error **  -                                                                       Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?). Please make sure that the argument [object Object] at index [0] is available in the UsersModule context.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel you can use `@Inject` or not, it depends really on you (for simple injectables you use it without anything in it), but problem here is, that there is no UserService exported in anything that is imported in the module

Comment: This seems to be a common problem for all my modules. Tell me what to fix? this repo https://github.com/bechterev/diplom.git

Comment: For just the `AuthenticationModule`, you need to have `imports: [UsersModule]` and the `UsersModule` needs to have `exports: [UsersService]` so that modules that import the `UsersModule` know that they can use the `UsersService

Comment: This error all modules, Nest can't resolve dependencies of the SupportRequestService (?, +).

Comment: watching your code: you dont need ISupportRequestService, as the class that is not extending anything is interface itself (you can even name the interface and class the same to point out that you only care about same interface and dont care if its instance of the class)

Answer (score 1):

All my services use the mongodb model. Therefore, you need to do the following in modules and services.

**user.module.ts**

```
@Module({
*imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'User', schema: UserSchema }])],*
  providers: [UserService],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService implements IUserService {
  constructor(
*@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<User>*
) {}
```

good example https://wanago.io/2021/08/23/api-nestjs-relationships-mongodb/

Answer (score 0):

The code in yours repo cannot be even compiled, so cannot help you almost at all. There are lack of things, ts-errors etc.

but from what i see:

- UsersModule has provider `UserService` but its not exporting it. Therefore NO OTHER MODULE would have access to it. You need to  export the UserService too.
- AuthModule do not imports UserService (and nothing exports it) so its not found at the time of Nest trying to match injects. What you can do is to add `imports: [UserModule]` in
  AuthModule (and also export UserService in UserModule).

And read again the documentation of modules and example project to see how imports, exports, controllers and providers works.

Comment: Sorry, I probably haven't fully updated the repository. Yes, I added the export in the user module and imported it in the authorization module, as in the manual. The error is still being reproduced early.f you can look at the repository again